# Why is replace not working in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remove '.', (dots) from a text, but every time I enter the command

```
"someurl.ch" -replace ".", ""
```

The output is blank, but if I enter:

```
"someurl.ch" -replace ".", "-"
```

The output is : ----------

I don't get why this is happening, can somebody please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-replace` operator uses Regular Expressions (RE) for its search parameter. In a regular expression, the dot `.` is a special character meaning "match any character". If you wish to match a literal dot, you need to 'escape' the dot; this is done in RE by prefixing it with a backslash `\`. So, you want

```bsh
"someurl.ch" -replace "\.",""
```

to delete the dot from the string.

You should read [`Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7) for more information about regular expressions in PowerShell. [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) has information about `-replace` and other operators that may use RE in PowerShell.